# splitting up strings to x amount of characters

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am trying to make a decrypter that decrypts code from the encrypter I made. I am getting this type error when I run the code though

```
     getcrypt = ''.join(map(Decrypt.get,split_up_into_sixteen_chars(x_str)))
TypeError: split_up_into_sixteen_cjars() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I'm fairly new to programming and not sure whats causing this. 
heres my code

```
Decrypt = {'1s25FF5ML10IF7aC' : 'A', 1s2afF5ML10I7ac' : 'a'} #I obviously have more than this but I'm trying to make it as simplified as possible
def split_up_into_sixteen_chars():
    while len(x_str)>0:
        v = x_str[:16]
        print(v)
x_str = (input())
getcrypt = ''.join(map(Decrypt.get,split_up_into_sixteen_chars(x_str)))
print(getcrypt)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined a function that takes no parameters:

```
def split_up_into_sixteen_chars():
```

yet you are passing it one:

```
split_up_into_sixteen_chars(x_str)
```

You need to tell Python that the function takes one parameter here, and name it:

```
def split_up_into_sixteen_chars(x_str):
```

The name used does not have to match the name that you pass in for the function call, but it *does* have to match what you use inside the function. The following function would also work; all I did was rename the parameter:

```
def split_up_into_sixteen_chars(some_string):
    while len(some_string) > 0:
        v = some_string[:16]
        print(v)
```

This works because the parameter `some_string` becomes a *local name*, local to the function. It only exists inside of the function, and is gone again once the function completes.

Note that your function creates an infinite loop; the length of `some_string` will either always be 0, or always be longer than 0. The length does not change in the body of the loop.

The following would work better:

```
def split_up_into_sixteen_chars(some_string):
    while len(some_string) > 0:
        v = some_string[:16]
        print(v)
        some_string = some_string[16:]
```

because then we replace `some_string` with a shorter version of itself each time.

Your next problem is that the function doesn't return anything; Python then takes a *default* return value of `None`. Printing is something else entirely, `print()` writes the data to your console or IDE, but the caller of the function does not get to read that information.

In this case, you really want a generator function, and use `yield`. Generator functions return information in chunks; you can ask a generator for the next chunk one by one, and that  is exactly what `map()` would do. Change the function to:

```
def split_up_into_sixteen_chars(some_string):
    while len(some_string) > 0:
        v = some_string[:16]
        yield v
        some_string = some_string[16:]
```

or even:

```
def split_up_into_sixteen_chars(some_string):
    while some_string:
        yield some_string[:16]
        some_string = some_string[16:]
```

because an empty string is 'false-y' when it comes to boolean tests as used by `while` and `if`.

As your `map(Decrypt.get, ...)` stands, if `split_up_into_sixteen_chars()` yields anything that is *not* present as a key in `Dycrypt`, a `None` is produced (the default value for `dict.get()` if the key is not there), and `''.join()` won't like that. The latter method can only handle strings.

One option would be to return a string default instead:

```
''.join(map(lambda chunk: Decrypt.get(chunk, ''), split_up_into_sixteen_chars(x_str)))
```

Now `''`, the empty string, is returned for chunks that are not present in `Decrypt`. This makes the whole script work for whatever string input you have:

```
>>> x_str='Hello world!'
>>> ''.join(map(lambda chunk: Decrypt.get(chunk, ''), split_up_into_sixteen_chars(x_str)))
''
>>> x_str = '1s25FF5ML10IF7aC'
>>> ''.join(map(lambda chunk: Decrypt.get(chunk, ''), split_up_into_sixteen_chars(x_str)))
'A'
```

Comment: That worked kinda, now I am getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: still getting a type error on getcrypt = ''.join(map(Decrypt.get.split... saying TypeError:sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Comment: @Inhale.Py: Your `Decrypt` mapping returns `None` too for any 16 characters it doesn't know about. `''.join()` can only handle strings however.

Comment: ignore this just a test to help another user
>test
>test

Comment: @Inhale.Py: Hereby ignored.. :-P